# Python--Combinations of three items from each of two lists for iteration

Tags: python

ANOTHER EDIT:
I think I may not have made the question clear enough. Each `Person` has a separate list of which tasks they can perform, and there's no guarantee that `Person1` will always have the first of the three tasks on the list. I've tried a couple of things that were suggested in answers, but neither gets the result I'm looking for. Using `zip` and `dict` only checks the combinations that use the `Person` objects in the same order they appear in the list, which gives me a bunch of incorrect answers. Using `itertools.combinations` solves that problem but tests every possible set of person-task combinations, which again gives me a bunch of combinations I don't want.

What I want to ultimately accomplish is to have a list `bad_options` that contains all sets of three `tasks` that cannot be covered by assigning one `task` to each `person`. I don't need every permutation (e.g. if the three `tasks` are `[Task1, Task3, Task6]` and `Person1, Person3, Person2` have them in that order, I don't want `[Task1, Task3, Task6]` to be added to `bad_options`. My apologies in advance if this isn't clear enough; if at this point I should be asking a new question, feel free to comment and say so and I'll take that route.

Based on answers below, I've tried:

```
for setup in setups:
    combo = dict(zip(setup, people))
    possibilities.append(combo)
for setup in possibilities:
    for task, person in setup.items():
        if not task in person.tasks:
            if not setup in bad_options:
                bad_options.append(setup)
            break
        else:
            pass
```

This is returning all the possible combinations of tasks as though none of them were covered, even when I directly set each `person.tasks` to ensure they should all be valid and the function should return nothing. What am I doing wrong now?

I have the following that I need to combine:

```
tasks = ['Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3', 'Task4', 'Task5', ...]
people = [Person1, Person2, Person3]
```

Each `Person` is an instance of a class, one of whose attributes is a list of the tasks that person can perform. I will have to assign three total tasks, one to each person. I want to make sure that all possible combinations of three tasks can be covered by the people available.

I've already built the code that will give me a list of all possible combinations of three tasks:

```
setups = (('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3'),
          ('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task4'),
          ('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task5'), ...)
```

(The reason I do this part separately is because there are also limits on which combinations of tasks can go together and I've already written a separate script to eliminate illegal combinations. I'd prefer not to have to duplicate that effort, but can do so if doing it this way is stupid).

I'm thinking I need a to use a `for` loop over `setups`, maybe with something like `itertools.combinations`? I'd be looking for the result to be a list of dicts, as in:

```
options = [['Task1' : Person1, 'Task2' : Person2, 'Task3' : Person3],
           ['Task1' : Person1, 'Task2' : Person2, 'Task4' : Person3], ...]
```

I'm lost on how to get that list of dicts. I assume the iteration over the list would be something like:

```
for option in options:
    for task, person in option.items():
        if task[0] in person[0].tasks and task[1] in person[1].tasks and task[2] in person[2].tasks:
            True
        else:
            bad_options.append(option)
```

`bad_options` would then be a list of the combinations of tasks that aren't properly covered, if any, right?

Bottom line question: how do I get that list of dicts, and is my code to iterate over it correct? Alternatively, I'm open to being told there's a better way to accomplish the goal. For extra credit, I'd benefit in the future from having a way to determine which tasks to train each person on so they can cover all possibilities (but ignore this if it's unclear or you can answer the first question but not this one).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe this is what you need (if the question is how to get list of dicts)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> tasks = ['Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3', 'Task4', 'Task5']
>>> people = [1, 2, 3]
>>> setups = itertools.combinations(tasks, len(people))
>>> options = [{task: person for task, person in zip(tasks, people)} for tasks in setups]
>>> options
[{'Task1': 1, 'Task2': 2, 'Task3': 3}, {'Task1': 1, 'Task2': 2, 'Task4': 3}, {'Task1': 1, 'Task2': 2, 'Task5': 3}, {'Task1': 1, 'Task3':
 2, 'Task4': 3}, {'Task1': 1, 'Task3': 2, 'Task5': 3}, {'Task1': 1, 'Task4': 2, 'Task5': 3}, {'Task2': 1, 'Task3': 2, 'Task4': 3}, {'Tas
k2': 1, 'Task3': 2, 'Task5': 3}, {'Task2': 1, 'Task4': 2, 'Task5': 3}, {'Task3': 1, 'Task4': 2, 'Task5': 3}]
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for, but could be easily modified to do what I want. I want the Person objects themselves to be in the dicts, not just the number associated with them.

Comment: Well, I made this example with numbers because I don't have your Person class code. Of course I expected, that you will make it with Person objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` and `dict()`

```
options = []

for tasks in setup:
    d = dict( zip(tasks,  [Person1, Person2, Person3]) )
    # {'Task1' : Person1, 'Task2' : Person2, 'Task3' : Person3}

    options.append(d)
```

---

In you code `task` and `person` are single elements, not lists - you can't use `[0]`, `[1]`,etc.

But you can do (using `for/break/else` construction)

```
for option in options:
    for task, person in option.items(): # single elements 
        if task not in person.tasks:
            bad_options.append(option)
            break
    else: # for/break/else construction
        print "OK:", option
```

Comment: I think this will do it, but I've run into another problem that I thought I knew how to deal with, so I can't test it just yet.

Comment: This seems promising, but apparently I'm still missing something. I can't fit my edited code in a comment, so it'll be in an edit to the OP shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id            # assign a simple ID to each Person

Person1 = Person(1)
Person2 = Person(2)
Person3 = Person(3)

people = [Person1, Person2, Person3]

setups = (
    ('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3'),
    ('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task4'),
    ('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task5'))

# Create a list of dictionaries combining each setup with people
options = [dict(zip(setup, people)) for setup in setups]

# Display the list

for option in options:
    for key, person in option.items():
        print key, person.id
    print
```

This would give you the following output:

```
Task1 1
Task2 2
Task3 3

Task1 1
Task2 2
Task4 3

Task1 1
Task2 2
Task5 3
```